# Display output of command executed in bash as it is executing

Tags: bash

I've got a line in my bash script like this:

```
echo "`some_command`"
```

Now, `some_command` executes for around 1-2mins and it keeps printing alerts/messages in that interval.

Problem is when I execute my bash script, the script has no output for 1-2mins and then directly displays the output after complete execution of `some_command`.

How can I make my bash script output `some_command` as it is executing? Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Other than just running `some_command`?

Comment: That's a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command substitution is capturing everything your command writes to standard output, then displayed all at once by the `echo` command. Just run the command by itself. (And when you *do* want a command substitution, use `$(...)` instead of backticks.)

```
some_command  # not echo "$(some_command)"
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this!! I feel like an idiot! Arghhhh! :(